# How can I retrieve data from a foreign key table in SQL with C#

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I'm trying to build my first application for learning purposes but I've hit a wall..

My goal is to retrieve data from a table labeled PC and several foreign key tables that has an ID and a string value. I was able to do a SQL query that retrieved all the information from the PC table (including foreign key ID's) but I want to be able to see the "brand" and "model" of a pc.

This is the error I get:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

My PC model in C# looks like this:

```
public class PC
{
    public int PC_ID { get; set; }
    public string PC_SERIAL { get; set; }
    public string PC_NAME { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PC_BRAND_ID { get; set; }
    public PCBrand PC_Brand { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PC_MODEL_ID { get; set; }
    public PCBrand PC_Model { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PC_OS_ID { get; set; }
    public PCOS PC_OS { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PC_NET_ID { get; set; }
    public PCNet PC_Net { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PC_RAM_ID { get; set; }
    public PCRam PC_Ram { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{PC_ID} - {PC_NAME} - {PC_SERIAL} - {PC_Model} - {PC_Brand} - {PC_OS} - {PC_Net} - {PC_Ram}";
    }
}
```

For instance, one of my foreign key tables looks like this:

```
namespace Inventory.Data.Model
{
    public class PCBrand
    {
        public int PC_BRAND_ID { get; set; }
        public string PC_BRAND { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is my code in my repository class:

```
private const string SqlGetAllPC = @"Select PC.PC_ID, PC.PC_NAME,
     PC_BRAND.PC_BRAND,PC_MODEL.PC_MODEL,PC_NET.
     PC_NET,PC_OS.PC_OS,PC_RAM.PC_RAM
        FROM PC
        INNER JOIN PC_BRAND on PC.PC_BRAND_ID=PC_BRAND.PC_BRAND_ID
        INNER JOIN PC_MODEL ON PC.PC_MODEL_ID=PC_MODEL.PC_MODEL_ID
        INNER JOIN PC_NET ON PC.PC_NET_ID=PC_NET.PC_NET_ID
        INNER JOIN PC_OS ON PC.PC_OS_ID=PC_OS.PC_OS_ID
        INNER JOIN PC_RAM ON PC.PC_RAM_ID=PC_RAM.PC_RAM_ID";

    public IEnumerable<PC> GetAllFromPc()
    {
        IEnumerable<PC> list = null;

        try
        {
            connector.OpenConnection();
            System.Data.DataTable data = connector.GetData(SqlGetAllPC);

            if (data != null && data.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                list = ConvertToPC(data);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            connector.CloseConnection();
        }

        return list;
    }

    private IEnumerable<PC> ConvertToPC(DataTable data)
    {
        List<PC> tmp = new List<PC>();

        foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
        {
            tmp.Add(new PC()
            {
                PC_ID = row.Field<int>(0),
                PC_SERIAL = row.Field<string>(1),
                PC_NAME = row.Field<string>(2),
                PC_BRAND_ID = row.Field<int>(3),
                PC_MODEL_ID = row.Field<int>(4),
                PC_OS_ID = row.Field<int>(5),
                PC_NET_ID = row.Field<int>(6),
                PC_RAM_ID = row.Field<int>(7),
            });
        }

        return tmp;
    }
}
```

And at last my button that retrieves the data

```
private void GetAllButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Data.Repositories.PCRepository newpc = new Data.Repositories.PCRepository();

   IEnumerable<Data.Model.PC> data = newpc.GetAllFromPc();

   if (data != null)
   {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       data.ToList()
           .ForEach(x=> sb.AppendLine(x.ToString()))
       MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
   }
}
```

With some editing I was able to retrieve from my PC table. But I also want to retrieve the PC's model/brand name from the `PC_Brand` and `PC_Model` table in my database:

[image]

Comment: which line in the code throws the exception?

Comment: I recommend dapper.  I would forget what you have there and start using it, because it'll make database access way simpler.

Comment: @Chetan It looks like tmp.Add(new PC() in the PCRepository

Comment: You should also define dto classes which are purely intended for data access when the data you're reading does not match your viewmodel or model usage.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for the suggestion. It might be simpler but my "mentor" told me I should try to see if I could make it work this way..

Comment: You've shown us select code. Not add. Stick a break point in that add method and step through.

Comment: Did your mentor not explain debugging?

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29181.msdn-forums-asking-questions.aspx#Helpful_Development_Techniques

Comment: Try running the query directly against the database and see if any column has NULL value in it. If the datatable has NULL value, it may fail to convert to int.

Comment: @Andy I am debugging, but as I'm trying to say I'm fairly new and I've hit a wall

Comment: @Chetan  The query works. I did try run it in SMSS and it works like it should.

Comment: I know the query works. but you need to check if the query result has any NULL value in it.. Did you check that? Instead of using object initializer syntax. create object of PC seperately by doing `PC pc = new PC();` then set it properties, `pc.PC_ID = row.Field<int>(0);` so on... and then add that object to the list `tmp.Add(pc)`. This will break at the exact property for which the type casting is failing

Comment: @Andy Thanks! I know that the the catch errow happens after the tmp.Add(new PC()) So I'll have to go try work something out on that one. I'll post an answer when I find the solution

Comment: @Chetan Sorry I communicated badly. The query works and there is no NULL values as I've inserted values in the table. I'll try see if it'll work by creating the object seperately. I'll get back.

Comment: You have `PC_MODEL.PC_MODEL,PC_NET.PC_NET,PC_OS.PC_OS,PC_RAM.PC_RAM` in query. Which to me looks like select string values from the respective tables but you are trying to assign them to `PC_MODEL_ID, PC_OS_ID, PC_NET_ID, PC_RAM_ID` etc. That's why the casting from string to integer is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SELECT` is reading what I take to be string values (PC_MODEL.PC_MODEL, PC_NET.PC_NET, PC_OS.PC_OS, PC_RAM.PC_RAM), but you are assigning them to integers, hence the invalid cast.

Why am I sure that these are strings?  Because of your joins.  You are joining on e.g. PC_MODEL_ID which are almost certainly integers.

Change your `SELECT` to:

```
SELECT PC.PC_ID, PC.PC_NAME, PC_BRAND.PC_BRAND,PC.PC_MODEL_ID, PC.PC_NET_ID, PC.PC_OS_ID,PC.PC_RAM_ID
FROM PC
INNER JOIN PC_BRAND on PC.PC_BRAND_ID=PC_BRAND.PC_BRAND_ID
INNER JOIN PC_MODEL ON PC.PC_MODEL_ID=PC_MODEL.PC_MODEL_ID
```

Note that you do not need all the other joins, if you are only selecting the integer values.

EDIT

The you need to change your select to

```
SELECT PC.PC_ID, PC.PC_SERIAL, PC.PC_NAME, 
PC_BRAND.PC_BRAND, PC.PC_BRAND_ID, 
PC_MODEL.PC_MODEL, PC.PC_MODEL_ID, 
PC_NET.PC_NET, PC.PC_NET_ID, 
PC_OS.PC_OS, PC.PC_OS_ID, 
PC_RAM.PC_RAM, PC.PC_RAM_ID 
FROM PC 
INNER JOIN PC_BRAND on PC.PC_BRAND_ID = PC_BRAND.PC_BRAND_ID 
INNER JOIN PC_MODEL ON PC.PC_MODEL_ID = PC_MODEL.PC_MODEL_ID 
INNER JOIN PC_NET ON PC.PC_NET_ID = PC_NET.PC_NET_ID 
INNER JOIN PC_OS ON PC.PC_OS_ID = PC_OS.PC_OS_ID 
INNER JOIN PC_RAM ON PC.PC_RAM_ID= PC_RAM.PC_RAM_ID
```

Now you can do something like this in ConvertToPC:

```
private static IEnumerable<PC> ConvertToPC(DataTable data)
{
    List<PC> tmp = new List<PC>();
    foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
    {
        tmp.Add(new PC()
        {
            PC_ID = row.Field<int>(0),
            PC_SERIAL = row.Field<string>(1),
            PC_NAME = row.Field<string>(2),
            PC_Brand = new PCBrand
            {
                PC_BRAND = row.Field<string>(3),
                PC_BRAND_ID = row.Field<int>(4)
            },
            PC_BRAND_ID = row.Field<int>(4),
            PC_Model = new PCModel
            {
                PC_MODEL = row.Field<string>(5),
                PC_MODEL_ID = row.Field<int>(6)
            },
            PC_MODEL_ID = row.Field<int>(6),
            PC_Net = new PCNet
            {
                PC_NET = row.Field<string>(7),
                PC_NET_ID = row.Field<int>(8)
            },
            PC_NET_ID = row.Field<int>(8),
            PC_OS = new PCOS
            {
                PC_OS = row.Field<string>(9),
                PC_OS_ID = row.Field<int>(10)
            },
            PC_OS_ID = row.Field<int>(10),
            PC_Ram = new PCRam
            {
                PC_RAM = row.Field<string>(11),
                PC_RAM_ID = row.Field<int>(12)
            },
            PC_RAM_ID = row.Field<int>(12)
        });
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

Please note that I have changed your code by as little as possible.  In practice I would do a lot of things very differently.  For example, all the foreign key ids are now duplicated: instead of having both an object of type PCModel and an int PC_MODEL_ID in your PC class, you only need the object PCModel, because it already contains the ID.

Comment: Hi Jonathan! Thanks for taking your time to answer. I updated my question, and in the end you can see what I did to get all the information from the PC table. I want to be able to get the information from the foreign key tables though. Like the brand or model from the PC. Any tips on how to do that?